# get cookie with specific name

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to check existence of a cookie in html,
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="a1">
<p id = "ttttt">a1 test</p>
</div>
<script>
function checkCookie() {
   $cookie_name = 'testhastin';

    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

    document.getElementById("ttttt").innerHTML = "set";
} else {

    document.getElementById("ttttt").innerHTML = "not set";
}
}
window.checkCookie(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but when i run this page, noting will happen for "a1 test". (meaning it does not change to "not set")

i want to check if a cookie exists on the page and if so show specific content.

i also tried this code and result was the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="a1">
<p id = "ttttt">a1 test</p>
</div>
<script>
function checkCookie() {
    var username = getCookie("testhastin");


    if (username != "") {
    document.getElementById("ttttt").innerHTML = "set";
} else {

    document.getElementById("ttttt").innerHTML = "not set";
}
}
window.checkCookie(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `noting will happen for "a1 test".` what does that mean? If there is no cookie set it must change to `not set`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it doesnt change to not set. here is the link of the page:
http://amulay.ir/test/

Comment: You are getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: isset is not defined` that is a PHP rendered code so handle accordingly with php code

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal could you please tell me what should i do exactly?
i updated my question, i tried another code but i didn't get the result.

Comment: Where is your getCookie function in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` is a PHP variable. `isset()` is a PHP functoin. You cannot use that in JavaScript.

As for fetching cookies use `document.cookiename`

```
// Setting a cookie
document.testhastin= "Akshay";
// Reading a cookie
var val = document.testhastin;
```

W3Schools Link : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp